# Using LD_PRELOAD on kernel level functions

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, ld-preload

Is it possible to override one of the linux kernel functions using `LD_PRELOAD`?

For instance, I want to change the `cookie_hash` function in `Linux/net/ipv4/syncookie.c` for the listening socket for my program `fooserver`. Can I do it using LD_PRELOAD, or I need to recompile the kernel for that?

Are there any other options?

Thanks,

Comment: LD_PRELOAD trick will work for dynamically linked libraries only. The code you are talking about is most likely statically linked. Or sitting in a loadable module if you are lucky. In this case you can replace the module..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: You don't see a severe security problem if a user could easily replace a kernel function?

Comment: Except for malware: why would you want to do this?

Comment: But then my changes will apply to all the applications and listen sockets. Is there anyway that I can make it exclusive to my program?

Comment: @olaf It is to run some research to see if I can find a better hash.

Comment: @Amir: And you use your production system for that? Good idea! And why use that in kernel-space? Just write the two variants as user code and benchmark properly.

Comment: @Olaf Sure. Unless it is possible for root only.

Comment: @Olaf sorry, I didn't understand: "Just write the two variants as user code"? What do you mean? How can I change the syncookie hash of the listen socket in user-space? Also wondering, while benchmarking, would that be a fair comparison or not?

Comment: Why not use a user-space driver? Use raw sockets and fine. Of course that can be fair if you do this properly.

Comment: Oh i see. If I want to test it in the wild, I need to reimplement the whole listen socket with my new syncookie hash for a server in prd. That is way to risky and troublesome... anyway, thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to use LD_PRELOAD to replace a function in the kernel.

You will need to either recompile the kernel.

If the function is in a kernel module, then you may be able to unload, recompile and reload the module without needing to restart the kernel.

If this is something you will be doing frequently, then you will want to use a second computer, or a virtual machine, so you won't have to keep restarting the computer you're programming on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use kprobes or systemtap to override kernel functions. It isn't necessary to recompile.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar in Linux Kernel.
It isn't a trivial operation but what you should do is the next:

1. Find the address of the function you want to be replaced. There are several ways to achieve the address. The simplest one is 'cat /proc/kallsyms | grep cookie_hash ".
2. From your module, you save the content of the address. It is the original 'cookie_hash' function.
3. Into this address, you place the address of your function 'my_cookie_hash'.
4. At the end of your function 'my_cookie_hash', you call the original function 'cookie_hash'.

There are many hidden traps and potential crashes, though. 
But generally, this approach works.